# How do you copy a group of cells over while changing their contents?

Tags: google-sheets

Okay, so the title might be misleading but it's the best I could come up with. I'm currently in the process of making a bot to solve Mastermind in Google Sheets because I thought it would be an interesting chalenge. I'm trying to add in a bunch of sets ((1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,2) etc.) with each of the numbers going up to 6. I want each one in a separate cell. Is there a way to copy this over easily without having to do it manually?[image]

Like this. And I have tried to use that thing in the bottom right corner of the cell, but it does it in a different way then I wanted it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to WebApps. You said _I'm trying to add in a bunch of sets ((1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,2) etc.) with each of the numbers going up to 6. I want each one in a separate cell_. No doubt you understand _exactly_ what you want and can visualise the outcome... BUT it is less clear to others, the description lacks clarity, and it doesn't convey what you are trying to do. Would you please edit your question to provide an example (as a table or even a snapshot) of the outcome that you are trying to achieve. Have you tried at all to solve this yourself? -  include anything that you've tried.

Comment: @Tedinoz Just edited it. Thank you.

Comment: Is the dot so important to you as a digit separator?

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain an array 6x6 like this:

[image: array]

in this way:

```
=transpose( arrayformula ({
int((row(A1:A6)-1)/216)+1 &mod(int((row(A1:A6)-1)/36);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A1:A6)-1)/6);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A1:A6)-1)/1);6)+1 
\ 
int((row(A7:A12)-1)/216)+1 &mod(int((row(A7:A12)-1)/36);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A7:A12)-1)/6);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A7:A12)-1)/1);6)+1
\ 
int((row(A13:A18)-1)/216)+1 &mod(int((row(A13:A18)-1)/36);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A13:A18)-1)/6);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A13:A18)-1)/1);6)+1
\ 
int((row(A19:A24)-1)/216)+1 &mod(int((row(A19:A24)-1)/36);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A19:A24)-1)/6);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A19:A24)-1)/1);6)+1
\ 
int((row(A25:A30)-1)/216)+1 &mod(int((row(A25:A30)-1)/36);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A25:A30)-1)/6);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A25:A30)-1)/1);6)+1
\ 
int((row(A31:A36)-1)/216)+1 &mod(int((row(A31:A36)-1)/36);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A31:A36)-1)/6);6)+1 &mod(int((row(A31:A36)-1)/1);6)+1
}))
```

the first row of the next array will start from row(A37:A42), while the last row of the 36th and last array will start from row(A1291:A1296)

**Note** that my system uses **comma** as decimal separator, **backslash** as a column separator in array and **semicolon** as parameter separator ... adapt the formula to your system

[here a test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HWFXT8LoQ9httdubTnkzqYCKOsiQuVu-OQiS5oDnFVU/edit?usp=sharing) where first two arrays have commas between values

[image: arrays]
In the same test spreadsheet but in another sheet, I used calculations with the Sequence () function instead, see if you prefer them
[image: SEQUENCE]

Comment: The OP wants comma-separated values in each cell. How would you adapt your answer for that?

Comment: not much of a problem ... I modified the first two arrays of the test sheet, inserting some ' & "," '

Comment: @Tedinoz
thank you very much for your link ... I did not know the SEQUENCE() function and I think that with it I will be able to simplify my procedure a lot

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer to your question. There is still some minor copy/paste special, copy as values to be done.

There are three steps to get the data:

**Step#1: Column A: Data**

Enter the values in Column A as shown in the screenshot.

**Step#2: Column B: Formula#1-List**

Enter this formula in Cell B2:

`=INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")&","&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")))&","&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")))&","&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""))))`

HT: @player0 [Generate all possible combinations for 3 Columns in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781895/1330560)

**Step#3: Column C: Formula#2-The Results**

- Enter the required number of Columns in cell D1 [Hint: the answer = 6(six)]
- Enter the following formula in Cell C2

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(split(transpose(SPLIT(Query(indirect(address(2,2,4,true)&":"&address(1297,2,4,true))&"❤"&if(MOD(row(indirect(address(2,2,4,true)&":"&address(1297,2,4,true)))-row(B1),D1)=0,"|",""),,9^9),"|")),"❤")))`

HT:  infoinspired.com [Split a Column into Multiple N Columns In Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-column-into-multiple-n-columns-sheets/)

From here you can convert the results from a formula to data (Copy, paste special, Paste as values, cut/paste the results as required.

---

[image: screenshot]